# Shape keys not exporting to FBX

Tags: export, shape-keys, .fbx

So I'm pulling my hair here. I cannot get Shape keys to export in FBX with Blender. I've tried by unckecking the "Apply Modifiers" box and trying with different export options from different forum answers I've encountered, none seem to work. The console doesn't say there's any problem and the only time it did, it was this:

**Error: Shapekey KEKey has an invalid 'from' pointer (0000000000000000), it will be deleted**

I've exported shape keys before without a problem, I don't understand what is going on and it happens only with this one file I've been working on. Please help, I've been stuck with this for a couple weeks now.

Here's the file in question.
[image]

Comment: I have updated my answer below to include an FBX round trip from your blend file.  Seemed to work okay.  not all of your (original) objects have shape keys.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following examples with a trivial shape key on a cube:

[image]

try exporting the cube as an FBX [image]

and then import into a new file session.  Here is the fbx I exported via [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1bsb6qh8xupmr6/untitled.fbx?dl=0)

blender v3.4.0

I you want someone to look at your particular example, delete all but the object of concern, and use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) to a link to your question.

EDIT/ADDED 15-Mar:
As you added your blend file, I have made a round-trip through an FBX export/import.  My resulting [FBX](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5w0gyqb2qpdon03/hairmodel7.fbx?dl=0) and imported into [image] appears to work fine in blender 3.4.0.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have added the blend file. And hope someone can see it. I've been able to export shape keys before. It's just this particular one that has not worked with anything I've tried.